# defining "user" from an input box in python 2.7.8

Tags: python, tkinter

im trying to make some code, so that when you type your name into the input box and hit the ok button, your name is then retrieved, and used as the text in a picture, my code is below.

```
from Tkinter import *
c = Canvas(width=500, height=500, bg='white')
c.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

master = Tk()

var = StringVar(master)
var.set("one") # initial value

option = OptionMenu(master, var, "one", "two", "three", "four")
option.pack()

#


def ok():
    print "value is", var.get()
    master.quit()
user = var.get()   ##### this is what im struggling with

button = Button(master, text="OK", command=ok)
user = var.get()

c.create_text(200,470,text="by "+user, anchor=N, justify=CENTER) # credits

mainloop()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you want to do? I have made some code which you enter your name into an entry box, when you hit ok your name is made into a label  on the same tk window as the entry box.

**Here is the code:**

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

label = Label(text='please enter you name:')
label.pack()

entry = Entry()
entry.pack()

def ok():
    type = ('Times', 20)
    name = entry.get()
    Label(text = name, font = type).pack()

button = Button(master, text="OK", command=ok)
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

give it a try and tell me if this is what you wanted or not!